# MySQL (5.7.27) ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: 18.04, permissions, mysql, password

As far as I know this question has been asked an answered several times. But in my case, is slightly different.

So when I install MySQL 2.7.27 I cannot access it via root or anything. I've followed a [different solution](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/mysql-resetting-a-lost-mysql-root-password/) and it got fixed.

But the next day I come and I cannot access my local MySQL server. The password that I set the day before is not working anymore and I have to re-install MySQL and do the same thing over and over.
Any thoughts?

I'm on a recently installed Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

After trying everything I've found the solution.

One of my workmates was giving me a dump that saves all databases (even the `mysql` internal database).

It was changing the root password.

#### How I found the solution

After I dump everything I enter mysql terminal client with my password, it worked. Then I update the privileges with

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

And I couldn't access with my own password. Checked if  could access with his password and I could.